# Virtualenv Command Not Found

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I couldn't get `virtualenv` to work despite various attempts. I installed `virtualenv` on MAC OS X using:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and have also added the `PATH` into my `.bash_profile`. Every time I try to run the `virtualenv` command, it returns:

```
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

Every time I run `pip install virtualenv`, it returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I understand that in mac, the `virtualenv` should be correctly installed in

```
/usr/local/bin
```

The `virtualenv` is indeed installed in `/usr/local/bin`, but whenever I try to run the `virtualenv` command, the command is not found. I've also tried to run the `virtualenv` command in the directory `/usr/local/bin`, and it gives me the same result:

```
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

These are the PATHs I added to my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Framework/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/site-packages
```

Any workarounds for this? Why is this the case?

Comment: Try adding a symlink to the virtualenv executable in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Where should I create the symlink? It's still not working despite I tried to add a symlink at the directory where I want to use virtualenv @justinfay

Comment: from looking at the paths above it could be something like, replace the last path in the command with the path to the actual virtualenv executable: `$ ln -s /usr/bin/virtualenv /Library/Framework/Python.framework/Version/2.7/lib/site-packages/virtualenv/virtualenv.py`

Comment: what worked for me was to add a symlink `ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: Doesn't work in a lubuntu

Comment: What if you try `pip install virtualenv --user` ? Also check the permissions of `/usr/local/bin/` (you wrote that it was indeed installed in /usr/local/bin/, so if it is not found it looks more like a permissions issue).

Comment: I tried adding Lazy Loading method to initialize virtualenv. Please see [this](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#lazy-loading) part in the documentation

Answer (score 433):

If you installed it with

```
pip install virtualenv
```

You need to run

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv
```

which puts it in `/usr/local/bin/`.

The above directory by default should be in your `PATH`; otherwise, edit your `.zshrc` (or .`bashrc`) accordingly.

Comment: on AWS EC2 instance with `Amazon Linux`, if you are trying Let's Encrypt's `certbot`, give this solution a try. This was the only suggestion that solved my virtualenv problem.

Comment: the output is `sudo: /usr/bin/easy_install: command not found`

Comment: Thankyou for this - but I wish I knew what witchcraft is at work here - what does "easy_install" do that regular pip doesn't do? i.e. Why does this work?

Comment: This worked for me on MacOs `python -m venv venv_name`

Comment: This only works most likely if python 3.6+ is the default when using the python command.

Comment: It keeps trying to use 2.7.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle because you're using `python -m` instead of `python3 -m`

Answer (score 309):

I faced the same issue and this is how I solved it:

1. The issue occurred to me because I installed virtualenv via pip as a regular user (not root). pip installed the packages into the directory `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`
2. When I ran pip as root or with admin privileges (sudo), it installed packages in `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`. This path might be different for you.
3. virtualenv command gets recognized only in the second scenario
4. So, to solve the issue, do `pip uninstall virtualenv` and then reinstall it with `sudo pip install virtualenv` (or install as root)

Comment: I followed your solution and got the message "...If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag". Finally sudo -H pip install virtualenv did the job for me (on OS X), thank you

Comment: what if root is not available on your machine?

Comment: Solved the problem. I guess this one can go into the global dir instead of `--user`.

Comment: This issue also happens when pip itself is installed in ~/.local/SOME_PATH. 
I `cp` ed everything in `site-packages` dir into `/usr/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages`, and `rm -rf`ed the original directory.

Comment: Step 4 was what I was looking for! I couldn't figure out how to get files out of ~/.local

Comment: Followed the above instructions and worked for me. @vettipayyan is not all that Vetti after all

Comment: I'm on Windows but the problem was the same. i.e. I'd installed the package from a regular command prompt. So I uninstalled it, then installed it again from an elevated prompt and `virtualenv` was recognised.

Comment: This solution also worked for me in Linux Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64

Comment: worked but I get this:
WARNING: The directory '/Users/devprofile/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.

Answer (score 87):

The simplest answer. Just:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

and then:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Or you maybe installed virtualenv with `sudo`, in that case:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

Comment: Wow! This is what did the trick for me. I am using `pyenv` by the way

Comment: This is the way to go for Mac OS X using brew.

Comment: Been fighting this for weeks and it has been hindering my limited time to work on a python project and this was the only solution to work for me on mac. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, using Sudo after uninstalling the previous version worked for me:
```
pip uninstall virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm on Mac with M1 silicon!

Answer (score 82):

```sh
python3 -m virtualenv virtualenv_name
```

or

```sh
python -m virtualenv virtualenv_name
```

Comment: worked for me without the 3. python -m virtualenv <name>

Comment: Always a good method of solving path issues with python.

Comment: worked for me: "python -m virtualenv myvirtualenv" in windwos 10 - 64 bytes.

Answer (score 51):

I had the same issue. I used the following steps to make it work

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv

sudo -H pip install virtualenv
```

That is it. It started working.

Usage of `sudo -H`----> `sudo -H:`  set `HOME` variable to target user's home dir.

Comment: It fixes for me exacly the same problem... why it's not checked as the solution?

Comment: Also worked for Ubuntu. I was having issues setting it up for digital ocean. This should be the solution.

Answer (score 47):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I also faced same error.
Following command worked:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Comment: `brew install python-virtualenv` does not exist

Comment: Worked like a charm on my 18.04, Thanks

Comment: Voted down to promote `apt` as a successor to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 43):

I had same problem on **Mac OS X El Capitan**.

When I installed `virtualenv` like that `sudo pip3 install virtualenv` I didn't have `virtualenv` under my command line.

**I solved this problem by following those steps:**

1. Uninstall previous installations.
2. Switch to super user account prior to `virtualenv` installation by calling `sudo su`
3. Install `virtualenv` by calling `pip3 install virtualenv`
4. Finally you should be able to access `virtualenv` from both `user` and `super user` account.

Comment: Works for macOS Big Sur 11.6

Comment: Works for macOS Ventura 13.3

Answer (score 22):

**Figure out the problem**

Try installing with the `--verbose` flag

```
pip install virtualenv --verbose
```

Output will look something like this

```
  ..
  Using cached virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/6f/86/3dc328ee7b1a6419ebfac7896d882fba83c48e3561d22ddddf38294d3e83/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=aa7e5b86cc8cdb99794c4b99e8d670f3 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/)
Installing collected packages: virtualenv

  changing mode of /home/manos/.local/bin/virtualenv to 755
Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
Cleaning up...
```

From the output we can see that it's installed at `/home/manos/.local/bin/virtualenv` so let's ensure PATH includes that.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

In my case we can clearly see that `/home/manos/.local/bin` is totally missing and that's why the shell can't find the program.

**Solutions**

We can solve this in many ways:

1. We can install directly to a specific directory by fiddling with pip options (not recomended).
2. Create appropriate symlinks at `/usr/local/bin` or similar.
3. Append `/home/manos/.local/bin` to PATH.
4. Install as sudo to install directly to `/usr/local/bin`

The two last options are probably the most sensible. The last solution is the simplest so therefore I will just show solution 3.

Add this to ~/.profile:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

Logout out and in again and it should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly. It should be the accepted answer and +1 for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 20):

Found this solution and this worked perfectly for me.

```
sudo -H pip install virtualenv
```

The -H sets it to the HOME directory, which seems to be the issue for most people.

Answer (score 16):

You are having this error :

```
zsh: command not found: virtualenv
```

Because most probably you tried to install virtualenv without typing sudo beforehand.

If you try to add it to /usr/local/bin, this may result on syntax errors as the packages are not properly isntalled/copied:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "build/bdist.macosx-12.0-x86_64/egg/platformdirs/__main__.py", line 16
    def main() -> None:
               ^
```

In case you have tried to install virtualenv via pip without sudo rights, you need first to uninstall it:

```
pip3 uninstall virtualenv
```

Then install it using sudo:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Next you just need to activate the env:

```
virtualenv env 
source env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 15):

Personally. I did the same steps you did on a fresh Ubuntu 20 installation (except that I used pip3). I got the same problem, and I remember I solved it this way:

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

Link to understand the [`-m <module-name>`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) notation.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I ran `pip show virtualenv` to get the information about virtualenv package. I will look similar to this and will also show location of the package:

```
user@machine:~$ pip show virtualenv
Name: virtualenv
Version: 16.2.0
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Ian Bicking
Author-email: ianb@colorstudy.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: setuptools
```

From that grab the part of location up to the `.local` part, which in this case is `/home/user/.local/`. You can find virtualenv command under `/home/user/.local/bin/virtualenv`.

You can then run commands like `/home/user/.local/bin/virtualenv newvirtualenv`.

Answer (score 11):

You said that every time you run the `pip install` you get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. What you need to do is the following:

1. Change Directory (go to to the one where the virtualenv.py) 
   `cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
2. If you do an `ls` you will see that the script is there `virtualenv.py`
3. Run the script like this:
   `python virtualenv.py --distribute /the/path/at/which/you/want/the/new/venv/at theNameOfTheNewVirtualEnv`

Hope this helps. My advice would be to research venvs more. Here is a good resource: https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Answer (score 9):

I had troubles because I used apt to install python-virtualenv package.
To get it working I had to remove this package with `apt-get remove python-virtualenv` and install it with `pip install virtualenv`.

Comment: Which leaves the question: Why the devil is my python3-virtualenv package broken?

Answer (score 7):

Ensure that `virtualenv` is executable.

If `virtualenv` is not found, running the full path (`/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`) should work.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem for a long time. 
I solved it by running these two commands, first is to install second is to activate the env:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv yourenvname
```

Note that I'm using `python3`, you can change it to just `python` if `python3` fails. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem can be solved using a simple **symbolic link**, but you are creating the symbolic link to the **wrong file**. As far as I know **virtualenv** is installed to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv`, (you can change the numbers for your Python version) so the **command** for creating the **symbolic link** should be:

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: setting up the sym link was all i needed to do. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

On ubuntu 18.4 on AWS installation with pip don't work correctly. 
Using apt-get install the problem was solved for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

and to check

```
virtualenv --version
```

Answer (score 5):

This works on Ubuntu 18 and above (not tested in previous versions):

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

Comment: I confirm it worked on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

**Same problem:**
So I just did `pip uninstall virtualenv`
Then  `pip install virtualenv`

```
pip install virtualenv --user
```

Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/30/96a02b2287098b23b875bc8c2f58071c35d2efe84f747b64d523721dc2b5/virtualenv-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv

**Then I got this :**

> The script virtualenv is installed in '/Users/brahim/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

which clearly says where it is installed and what to do to get it

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Linux, open your terminal and type **virtualenv** halfway and autocomplete with tab key. If there's no auto-completion install virtualenv on your system by running:

```
mycomp$sudo apt-get install virtualenv
//if you're already super user.
mycomp#apt-get install virtualenv
```

You can now navigate to where you want to create your project and do:

```
myprj$pip3 install virtualenv    
//to install python 3.5 and above  
myprj$virtualenv venv --python=python3.5  
//to activate virtualenv  
(venv)myprj$source venv/bin/activate  
(venv)myprj$deactivate
```

Comment: I upgraded to python 3.7. I kept trying to install virtualenv, it will always return "Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)". I read somewhere that from a certain python 3.x version it comes with virtualenv installed, but trying to create a virtual environment simple, didn't work, it would return error that it doesn't know the virtualenv command. But it worked with the following command from your answer, "virtualenv venv --python=python3.7". Nothing else done prior. In case it helps anyone else. MacOS environment.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using

```
sudo
```

In this case, at first you need to uninstall the pipenv and then install again using sudo command.

1. `pip uninstall pipenv`
2. `sudo pip install pipenv`

Answer (score 1):

Follow these basic steps to setup the virtual env

```
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
sudo rm -rf ~/get-pip.py ~/.cache/pip
```

we need to update our `~/.bashrc`

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The `~/.bashrc` file is simply a shell script that Bash runs whenever you launch a new terminal. You normally use this file to set various configurations. In this case, we are setting an environment variable called `WORKON_HOME`  to point to the directory where our Python virtual environments live. We then load any necessary configurations from virtualenvwrapper .

To update your `~/.bashrc` file simply use a standard text editor, nano  is likely the easiest to operate.
A more simple solution is to use the cat  command and avoid editors entirely:

```
echo -e "\n# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After editing our ~/.bashrc  file, we need to reload the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now that we have installed virtualenv  and virtualenvwrapper , the next step is to actually create the Python virtual environment — we do this using the mkvirtualenv  command.

```
mkvirtualenv YOURENV
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing Angela Yu's online iOS course and I was getting same problem plus also was getting permission denied error 13 when I was trying to run `virtualenv --python=/{myPath} {newVirtualEnvName}`

**I solved it by:**

1. switching to sudo user `sudo su`
2. navigating to my destination folder (where I want my new virtual env to live) ie. */Users/muUserName/Environments/*
3. run command `python -m virtualenv python27` where ***python27*** is a name of my new virtual environment
4. above created folder ***pathon27*** in my ***Environments*** folder, and then I was able to run `source python27/bin/activate` to start my virtualenv

Comment: switching to `sudo su` worked for me, even though i wanted to use python3 as the venv folder to be created. It seems that it's a permissions issue when trying to install locally and the elevated sudo not finding the correct path unless explicitly logged in as root

Answer (score 1):

on Mac

> > pip3 install virtualenv
> > python3 -m virtualenv [venv_name_you_want]

Q. virtualenv not found
After installing virtualenv, virtualenv exist on the pip3 list. But When to use the **"virtualenv [venv_name]"** command, it returns "virtualenv not found".

A. Because virtualenv is installed as a module in python3. Not installed as a command tool like python3 in the "/usr/bin/.." path. So this case we can use **"python3 -m virtualenv [venv_name]"**.

And we can see where it is to retry this command **"pip3 install virtualenv"**. Then zsh or your shell tells us kindly this info.

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/[your-usr-name-here]/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (20.16.5)
> Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.4.1 in /Users/[your-usr-name-here]/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.8.0) ...

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading MacOS Monterey from 12.5.1 to 12.6, I was no longer able to run `virtualenv`. Since I had [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) on my mac, installed like this:

```
$ brew install virtualenv
...
==> Installing virtualenv
==> Pouring virtualenv--20.16.5.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
    /usr/local/Cellar/virtualenv/20.16.5: 949 files, 20.3MB
==> Running `brew cleanup virtualenv`...
...
```

Of course, `brew` decided to upgrade various other packages I had as well, but `virtualenv` was available again thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it with

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Now to use it you need to type this command:

```
python -m virtualenv name_of_your_virtualenv
```

in order to activate it:

```
.\name_of_your_virtualenv\Scripts\activate
```

if you face a problem activating your virtualenv, it could be Execution Policy Settings. To fix it, you should try executing this command in your command line: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`. This would allow PowerShell will run the script.

Comment: No need to go for other commands, just install the virtualenv as root user privilege. like this: sudo pip install virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

For me it was installed in this path (python 2.7 on MacOS):
$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that if you are not a sudo user as I was not one.You need to add path of your bin folder (`/home/myusername/.local/bin`).So basically the command line searches in which of these path is the command which you have typed.

```
export PATH=/home/b18150/.local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

here it will search in `local/bin` first then `/usr/bin` and then `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

```
pip3 install virtualenv
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
python -m venv <name of virtual env>
source <path to Virtual env folder/bin/activate>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install ufw python virtualenv git unzip pv
```

3 commands and everything working!

Comment: The question is for mac OS, there is no `apt`

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

Comment: Did you see that he was asking for Mac OSX?