# Setting up a virtual environment for Django on a Mac

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have been following an online tutorial 'Install Django on Mac'.
However, I have hit a problem ....

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:~ Lizzie2$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:~ Lizzie2$ virtualenv mysite
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:~ Lizzie2$
```

As you can see when I attempt to create a virtual environment the response I get is 'command not found'?
Are you able to shed any light on what might be causing the problem and how I can resolve it?
Ultimately I want to install Django.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `virtualenv` is a python module, not a command. `pip` adds modules in pyhton install.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31133050/1005215