# Virtualenv on remote machine gives command not found, even after path reset.

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, virtualenv, tcsh

First, background: I'm an undergraduate student in physics and mathematics. I have experience programming in Python, and I've gained a lot of experience with using various shell programs while trying to solve this problem.

I'm needing to run some software on a cluster at my University. I'm trying to do this by running ssh from my mac to the machine. I've been having a lot of trouble installing packages because of permissions, so I thought I would try using virtualenv.

Despite the fact that other packages would not install, virtualenv seemed to install. However, when I try to run it, I get

```
virtualenv: Command not found.
```

In trying to solve my problem, I tried reinstalling it and got

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages.
```

I though maybe the issue was that my path was not set right. The remote machine is using tcsh, and so I ran

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}/local/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

and the path now is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/sparc-solaris-10:/local/bin:/usr/plocal/bin:/usr/local/bin/X11:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/bin:
/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/bin/X11:
/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/pbmplus:/usr/local/X11R5/bin:/usr/local/plot79:/usr/java/bin:
/usr/local/java/bin:
/usr/local/hotjava/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:
/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/5bin:
/usr/local/etc:/etc:/usr/plocal/sun/bin:./local/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Yet, it remains that if I try to run virtualenv, it claims that the command is not found!

FULL DISCLOSURE: This question is similar to the following question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found). But, the solution there won't work for me because I can't use sudo:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Bad file number
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
Segmentation fault
```

As another note, I have emailed the guy in charge of all the Unix stuff to help me with, as have my advising professors, and he has done nothing. If at all possible, it would be best if there were a way to do this that did not involve me needing to get permissions from him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `virtualenv` in `.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages` means that you've installed it only for you using `--user` option; hence the scripts are in `~/.local/bin`. So do

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:$HOME/.local/bin
```