# I am trying to create a webapp using django framework

Tags: python, django

I have installed django and then tried using the command line to make a virtual environment then oops it gives me this error

"'"virtualenv"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

what should I do to correct this

Comment: Did you install virtualenv?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualenv Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)

Comment: How to create virtual environments is well documented. You can do a little bit of research on your error and find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on python3 , use `python3 -m venv <env-name>` , env-name being your preferred name for your virtual env.

Also you get that error because virtualenv is not installed on your system. You can install with `pip install virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install "virtualenv". It's not inbuilt.

If you are a beginner I would suggest using anaconda prompt. It's easier to create/activate/deactivate environments in it.

For more information look here:

- [For installing/using virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)
- [For anaconda prompt](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)