# ' rq command not found ' when starting worker

Tags: python, server, redis, jobs, worker

I am trying to do some background jobs using redis and rq on macOS Catalania. I successfully installed redis and rq ( rq = 1.1.0 with `$ pip3 install rq`), but when I try to execute the command `$ rq worker`, no matter in what directory I am in, it just gives me `-bash: rq: command not found`. Does anyone know why this might happen?

I tried the following:

1. uninstalled rq and installed it with sudo -- same error
2. unistalled rq and installed an older version of rq (0.13.0) -- same error
3. searched the rq command with double tab and there was nothing related to rq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I answer my question so other people that may face the same problem can see the answer here.

`The solution has been nicely presented here:` [Virtualenv Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)