# Getting an error in Jenkins with integration Python-Behave-Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, python-behave

I am trying to connect jenkins with my script but it shows me an error in the Console Output:
I am using Python + behave + selenium

**This is my virtualenv builder**

> '#!/bin/sh echo   '#### Create Virtual Environment ####'
>   VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME='virtual-environment'   virtualenv $VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME
>
> echo '#### Activate Virtual Environment ####'   source
>   $VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate
>
> echo '#### Install requirements ####' pip install -r
>   ./Users//.jenkins/workspace/X-Automation-test/requirements.txt
>
> echo '#### Run tests ####' make all
>
> echo ### deactivate virtual environment ### deactivate

**Error in the Console Output**

````
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/<my user>/.jenkins/workspace/X-Automation-test
[X-Automation-test] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/l6/ggw3mk7x2jx5lwdcjnyh4yjr0000gn/T/shiningpanda5769608622999070407.sh
+ echo '#### Create Virtual Environment ####'
#### Create Virtual Environment ####
+ VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME=virtual-environment
+ virtualenv virtual-environment
/var/folders/l6/ggw3mk7x2jx5lwdcjnyh4yjr0000gn/T/shiningpanda5769608622999070407.sh: line 5: virtualenv: command not found
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Answer (score 1):

It looks (from your stack trace) that you are getting this error:

```
line 5: virtualenv: command not found
```

I would recommend you to look through the answers for this specific error here:
[Virtualenv Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)

Another option that worked for me is to use a Jenkins plugin for building a virtual environment instead of the shell script, this is the plugin: [ShiningPanda Virtualenv Builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59508184)

I hope this helps, good luck!