# zsh: command not found: virtualenv in Window Subsystem For Linux (WSL)

Tags: ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, oh-my-zsh

I recently switched to **WSL2** and using `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` after that I installed `pip` and later I installed `virtualenv` using `pip install virtualenv`, it successfully installed the package but when I am trying to create a virtual environment, it is not working I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

**NOTE** 
I am using `zsh` shell with `oh-my-zsh`

**Current Path of `virtualenv`**

`/home/<myUsername>/.local/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virtualenv Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I solved my problem by uncommenting

`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` from `.zshrc` file and adding `:$HOME/.local/bin`

**FINAL COMMAND** 
`export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin`