# Unable to create a venv in EC2 using user data

Tags: python, linux, bash, terraform

I'm launching an EC2 instance using Terraform with a user data script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
sudo yum -y install wget
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.10/Python-3.9.10.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.9.10.tgz

cd Python-*/
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.bash_profile

pip3.9 install virtualenv
```

I know that this works fine because I've created a log for this user data script and sure enough the last few lines show that virtualenv was successfully installed. It works if I do it manually too.

A second Bash script is executed at the same time via SSH. It sleeps first to give the user data script enough time to fully execute before attempting to create a virtual instance with the virtualenv library:

```
#!/bin/bash


sleep 210
virtualenv myenv
```

This script gives the user data script plenty of time to finish, but *myenv* is never created. I know the second script SSH connection is fine because I've made it print to my local console. If I do execute all this manually there are no problems. If I attempt to create the venv in the user data script it fails too. The error I get:

```
aws_instance.example (remote-exec): /tmp/script.sh: line 5: virtualenv: command not found
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

User-data script is [executed as root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). Try changing user to root and check if that has virtualenv available.
You can change to root user in your terminal using this command.

```
sudo su
```

It looks it is not available in your case, you can fix it by following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found).